# Can "Minor Conjuration" be used to create food?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard, food-and-drink

Let's say a wizard of second level has gotten themselves out in the middle of nowhere with no sources of food. Could they use minor conjuration to summon a loaf of bread, or a cookie? Or would taking a bite out of the food cause it to take "damage" ending the duration?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Sisyphean Food

**You can make it, but you won't be nourished**

Minor Conjuration from the [Wizard subclass School of Conjuration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/phb/classes#SchoolofConjuration) states:

> conjure up an inanimate object in your hand or on the ground in an unoccupied space that you can see within 10 feet of you...The object disappears after 1 hour, when you use this feature again, or if it takes or deals any damage.

As you had stated, taking a bite of it would definitely constitute'taking damage' as it is no longer in it's original state. Once 'damaged', the object disappears which would include whatever you put in your mouth.

Also note that the Conjured object is clearly magical when observed (thanks @SirCinnamon!):

> The object is visibly magical, radiating dim light out to 5 feet.

Comment: So I could use it to summon trick food that disappears as soon as someone tries to eat it... Excellent.

Comment: @NoelleB Keep in mind the food would be "visibly magical" according to the restrictions on minor conjuration

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113713/discussion-on-answer-by-nautarch-can-minor-conjuration-be-used-to-create-food).

Comment: The ultimate diet food!  Zero-calorie deep-fried bacon peanut-butter ice cream balls, here I come!

Comment: Good answer, though I think a much more appropriate title would be "Tantalean food" if you want to reference Greek mythology