# What happens if a creature eats food created by a College of Creation bard?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, unearthed-arcana, bard, food-and-drink

If a [College of Creation bard](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/UA2020_02_06_Subclasses2.pdf) uses their Performance of Creation to summon rations, and then eats the rations, will they still be hungry at the end of their next turn?  What if they maintain the summoning for 10 minutes to extend its time to their bard level hours, then do the rations they summon fill creature's hunger?

> As an action, you can create one nonmagical
>   item of your choice in an unoccupied space
>   within 10 feet of you. The item must appear on a
>   surface or in a liquid that can support it. The gp
>   value of the item can’t be more than 20 times
>   your bard level and must be Large or smaller.
>   {snip}  For examples of items you can
>   create, see the Armor, Weapons, Adventuring
>   Gear, Tools, and Mounts and Vehicles tables in
>   chapter 5, “Equipment,” of the Player’s
>   Handbook.
>
> The created item disappears at the end of your
>   next turn, unless you use your action to maintain
>   it. Each time you use your action in this way, the
>   item’s duration is extended to the end of your
>   next turn, up to a maximum of 1 minute. If you
>   maintain the item for the full minute, it
>   continues to exist for a number of hours equal to
>   your bard level.
>
> Once you create an item with this feature, you
>   can’t do so again until you finish a long rest or
>   until you expend a spell slot of 5th level or
>   higher to use this feature. You can have only one
>   item created by this feature at a time; if you use
>   this action and already have an item from this
>   feature, the first one immediately vanishes.

Comment: I think this is related: "[Can "Minor Conjuration" be used to create food?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124977)"

Comment: Related: [Can the Prestidigitation cantrip create an "infinite" supply of food and water by repeatedly creating these trinkets?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/195980/23547)

Answer (score 4):

## Sisyphean Food

**You can make it, but you won't be nourished**

Performance of Creation from the UA College of Creation states:

> As an action, you can create one nonmagical item of your choice in an unoccupied space within 10 feet of you...
>
> The created item disappears at the end of your next turn, unless you use your action to maintain it. Each time you use your action in this way, the item’s duration is extended to the end of your next turn, up to a maximum of 1 minute. If you maintain the item for the full minute, it continues to exist for a number of hours equal to your bard level.

Once the duration has concluded, the item will disappear. Which means whatever is in your stomach also disappears. You may feel full for a few hours, but that's about it.

### What about digestion and evacuation?

This isn't really a part of D&D mechanics, so it'll be up to a DM to decide. If they feel that it's been inside you long enough to be processed and that resulting nutrients remain, which is doubtful as their source is gone as if it was never there, a DM could rule that the effects of eating remain. But that's really up to them.

Comment: Good answer, though I think a more appropriate title would be "Tantalean food"

Answer (score -1):

The rules for this subclass have changed. Now it states the following:

> Also at 3rd level, as an action, you can channel the magic of the Song of Creation to create one nonmagical item of your choice in an unoccupied space within 10 feet of you. The item must appear on a surface or in a liquid that can support it. The gp value of the item can't be more than 20 times your bard level, and the item must be Medium or smaller. The item glimmers softly, and a creature can faintly hear music when touching it. The created item disappears after a number of hours equal to your proficiency bonus. For examples of items you can create, see the equipment chapter of the Player's Handbook.

> Once you create an item with this feature, you can't do so again until you finish a long rest, unless you expend a spell slot of 2nd level or higher to use this feature again. You can have only one item created by this feature at a time; if you use this action and already have an item from this feature, the first one immediately vanishes.

> The size of the item you can create with this feature increases by one size category when you reach 6th level (Large) and 14th level (Huge).

According to this, you can be nourished for the number of hours it lasts, but then you become hungry again. It could be used to satisfy yourself until you can find some real food, though.